# Find Verbs in a String

Tags: c, pointers, user-defined-functions, binary-search

I am trying (and having trouble) to write a program (In C) that accepts a string in the command line (eg. $ test.out "This is a string") and looks through the string to find verbs (and nouns, but if I figure out verbs, I can do nouns on my own).

A list of aplphabetically sorted verbs is given in the file lexicon.h, and is what I am supposed to use as my dictionary.

I know how to accept the string from the command line and use that input to create an array of strings, each string itself being a separate word, and I already have a working program that can do that, and that I hope to use part of for this one.

I am supposed to create a function called binary_search(...stuffgoeshere...) and use that to search through the lexicon file and find the verb.

I would like some suggestions or guidance on how to create a function (binary_search) that can check to see if an already separated word matches any on the list in lexicon.h.  I do not want someone to just write an answer, I would like to know why you are suggesting what you do.  Hopefully I can learn something fun out of this!

I know it's messy, but this is what I have so far.

Also note that lexicon's verb array has 637 values (as seen when I make int size = 637)
This program does not compile anymore, as I have not yet figured out how to make the binary_search function work yet.  I am trying to modify a binary search function used in an example for class, however, that one sorted numbers in a text file, not strings of characters.

If there is anything else I should include, let me know.  Thank you for your help!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "lexicon.h"

    int binary_search(char word[], char verbs[][], int size);

    int
    main(int argc, char*argv[])
    {
            char word[80];
            char str[80],
                 args[80][80];
            int counter = 0,
                a = 0,
                i = 0,
                index = 0,
                t = 0;
            while(str[a] != '\0')
            {
                    if(str[a] == ' ')
                    {
                            args[index][i] = '\0';
                            i = 0;
                            a++;
                            index ++;
                            counter ++;
                    }
                    args[index][i++] = str[a++];
            }
            args[index][i] = '\0';
            counter = counter + 1;
            printf("\nThe verbs were: ");
            int verbposition= -1;
         int size = 637;
            while(t<counter)
            {
                    strcpy(word, args[t]);
                    verbposition = binary_search(word, verbs, size);

                    if(verbposition > -1)
                            printf("%s", args[t]);

                    t++;

            }

            return 0;
    }

    int
    binary_search(char word[], char &verbs[][], int size)
    {
            int bottom = 0,
      top = size - 1,
                found = 0,
                middle;
            while(bottom <= top && !found)
            {
                    middle = (bottom + top) / 2;

                    if(strcmp(word, verbs[middle]))
                    {
                            found = 1;
                            return = middle;
                    }
                    if(strcmp(word, verbs[middle]) > 0)
                    {
                            top = middle - 1;
                    }
                    else
                            bottom = middle + 1;   
     }
            return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Recommend that you state a concise question at the beginning.

Comment: Your `if(strcmp(word, verbs[middle]))` does not behave as you want it to, try to check what `strcmp()` returns if you give it two equal strings. Will that result trigger the if?

Comment: In binary_search replace "strcmp(word, verbs[middle])" with "int cmp = strcmp(word, verbs[middle]);" and test that variable so you will not need to do a computationally expensive strcmp() twice.  This does not reduce your order-of-complexity, but is a nice touch.  Also as @cybrhuman hints, test cmp against == 0 in the first if(), and > 0 in the 2nd if().

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. I would highly suggest you to use print statements as you will have a clear idea of where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

At only 637 entries your "binary search" could just be a for loop walking whatever the dictionary structure that is in the lexicon.h file doing a string compare on each element.

A better answer that probably goes way beyond the requirement is to properly parse the input string as tokens. Here's a short list of common suffixes for many adjectives and verbs. As well a a short list of noun modifiers adjacent to nouns.

- adj suffix - able, ible, al, ful, ian, ive, less, like, ous.
- verb suffix - ate, an, ify, ise, ing.
- noun modifiers (whole words)- a, an, with, the, of.

Not an exhaustive list by any means but more than enough to get you started. I tossed them all in ENUMS by category, walk each enum with a for loop, and spit out the appropriate token if the token I am searching has a match to any of the suffixes or modifiers.

No dictionary lookups needed. Generally this example can identify 10k or so of the most common vocabulary words. There is some overlap with shared prefixes and suffixes when you start implementing the full list, but this will allow you to identify a lot of words quickly and easily.

To extend this you will want to implement sentence structure rules, tokenize phrases, and do some common patterns.

P.S. It's a deep rabbithole. Also the official designators for nouns.... NN for a common noun and NNP for proper nouns. There are similar designators when you get into parts of speech for all the word types.